# Salto de línea en un arraylist

Tags: java, consola

Soy nueva y estoy empezando a programar y primer post en stack. Estoy haciendo un programa de una biblioteca por consola en Java. He realizado un método que lo que hace es darme una lista de todos los libros que hay en la biblioteca, pero visualmente no me gusta como se visualiza y me gustaría que apareciera como si fuera un salto de línea.
A continuación pongo el código del método y mi intento de realizar un salto de línea:

```
 public static void mostrarTodosLibros(ArrayList<Libro> libroList){
        System.out.println("\n"+libroList +"\n");
    }
```

en el main de la aplicación llamó al método de la siguiente manera:
 `Biblioteca.mostrarTodosLibros(myList);`

Y en la consola se visualizan los libros de la biblioteca por comas y sin ningún salto de línea:

```
    [Libro{isbn='001a', titulo='El quijote', autor='Cervantes', editorial='el quijote pum', numCopias=5, numCopiasDisponibles=5}, Libro{isbn='002a', titulo='El principito', autor='Antoine de Saint-Exupéry', editorial='Editoriales Ignatius', numCopias=5, numCopiasDisponibles=5}, Libro{isbn='003a', titulo='50 Sombras de Grey', autor='Sam Taylor-Wood', editorial='Editoriales Maitus', numCopias=5, numCopiasDisponibles=5}, Libro{isbn='004a', titulo='La casa de Bernarda Alba', autor='Lorca', editorial='Lorca Editorial', numCopias=5, numCopiasDisponibles=0}, Libro{isbn='005a', titulo='100 años de soledad', autor='Garcia Marquez', editorial='Editorial Garcia', numCopias=5, numCopiasDisponibles=5}]
```

**Y lo que quiero es que este listado se me muestre de está manera por consola de manera más visual:**

[Libro{isbn='001a', titulo='El quijote', autor='Cervantes', editorial='el quijote pum', numCopias=5, numCopiasDisponibles=5},

Libro{isbn='002a', titulo='El principito', autor='Antoine de Saint-Exupéry', editorial='Editoriales Ignatius', numCopias=5, numCopiasDisponibles=5},

Libro{isbn='003a', titulo='50 Sombras de Grey', autor='Sam Taylor-Wood', editorial='Editoriales Maitus', numCopias=5, numCopiasDisponibles=5},

Cabe destacar que en el arraylist de myList introducimos los datos de dos maneras distintas, por una parte por un método llamado agregarlibros y por otra la tradicional que sería

`myList.add(new Libro("002a", "El principito", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", "Editoriales Ignatius", 5, 5));`

¿Hay alguna manera para que se visualice mejor?
Por otra parte y sé que no tiene que ver con la pregunta de arriba, ¿es posible utilizar una base de datos de mysql utilizando la consola? y si es posible, ¿hay alguna página web que me podáis dar para ver más información del tema?

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No quiero decir que la manera en la que lo estas haciendo esta mal, pero yo lo haria de esta:

Separa la clase libro y biblioteca para que haya mas orden.

A la clase libro le pondria en su constructor con los datos que solicitas y a la clase biblioteca agregarias cada libro con los respectivo metodos **agregar_libro(Libro)** que recibe un libro y automaticamente lo va almacenando en un **ArrayList** donde iran todos los libros y para mostrar los libros que ya tienes usarias el metodo **mostrar_lista_libro()** que se encargara de recorrer la La lista de libros que ya tiene. Teniendo esto solo llamas a la clase biblioteca y usas los 2 metodos que tiene en su interior. Espero te sirva

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solucion{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Biblioteca b = new Biblioteca();
        b.agregar_libro(new Libro("001a", "El quijote", "Cervantes", "el quijote pum", 5, 5));
        b.agregar_libro(new Libro("002a", "El principito", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", "Editoriales Ignatius", 7, 7));
        b.mostrar_lista_libro();
    }
}

class Biblioteca{

    private ArrayList<Libro> lista_libros = new ArrayList<Libro>();

    public void agregar_libro(Libro l){

        lista_libros.add(l);
    }

    public void mostrar_lista_libro(){

        for(int i = 0; i < lista_libros.size(); i++){

            System.out.println(lista_libros.get(i).toString()+"\n");
        }
    }
}

class Libro{

    private String isnb, titulo, autor, editorial;
    private int numCopias, numCopiasDisponibles;

    public Libro(String isnb, String titulo, String autor, String editorial, int numCopias, int numCopiasDisponibles){
        
        this.isnb = isnb;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.editorial = editorial;
        this.numCopias = numCopias;
        this.numCopiasDisponibles = numCopiasDisponibles;
    }

    public String toString(){

        String datos = "isnb: "+isnb+"\nTitulo: "+titulo+"\nAutor: "+autor+"\nEditorial: "+editorial+"\nNumero de copias: "+numCopias+"\nNumero de Copias disponible"+numCopiasDisponibles;
        return datos;
    }
}
```